# UIButton frame doesn't change if its panned

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uipangesturerecognizer

[Here is an image of a simple APP I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqnRB.png)

The App has a pan gesture recogniser for the centre purple button, the button when moved if it intersects with any of the 4 orange buttons, the purple button animates and moves inside the bounds of button it intersects otherwise it animates back to the initial starting position i.e centre.

For the first time when I pan the purple button the frame of the button updates, but If I try for the second time the frame of button remains the same (the value when it's at the centre of the view).

I am guessing this is something related to Auto Layout that I am missing, because if I remove the constrains on the centre purple button the frame updates every time correctly if I pan.

Can anybody explain what I have to keep in mind when animating with constraints

Here is my code for handling the Pan gesture:

```
@objc func handleCenterRectPan(_ pannedView: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let fallBackAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, dampingRatio: 0.5) {
                if self.button1.frame.intersects(self.centerRect.frame) {
                    self.centerRect.center = self.button1.center
                } else if self.button2.frame.contains(self.centerRect.frame) {
                    self.centerRect.center = self.button2.center
                } else if self.button3.frame.contains(self.centerRect.frame) {
                    self.centerRect.center = self.button3.center
                } else if self.button4.frame.contains(self.centerRect.frame) {
                    self.centerRect.center = self.button4.center
                } else {
                    // no intersection move to original position
                    self.centerRect.frame = OGValues.oGCenter
                }
        }

        switch pannedView.state {
        case .began:
            self.centerRect.center = pannedView.location(in: self.view)
        case .changed:
            print("Changed")
            self.centerRect.center = pannedView.location(in: self.view)
        case .ended, .cancelled, .failed :
            print("Ended")
            fallBackAnimation.startAnimation();
            //snapTheRectangle()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: what constraints you have given to purple button?

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh center horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be giving constraints if your aim is to move your views smoothly. And If you can't resist from constraints than you have to keep updating constraints and not the frames (centre), 
In your code, I assume you have given your purple button centre constraints and then you are changing button's centre as user drag using the pan gesture. The problem is constraints you have given are still active and its try to set it back as soon as layout needs to update.

So what you can do is

Don't give constraints as its need to move freely when user drag

OR

Create IBoutlet for constraints and set .isActive to false when user dragging and make it true if it's not inside any of the other buttons and update UpdateLayoutIfNeeded, so it will come back to original position. (good approach)

```
@IBOutlet var horizontalConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!            
@IBOutlet var verticalConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!

//make active false as the user is dragging the view
horizontalConstraints.isActive = false
verticalConstraints.isActive = false
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

//make it true again if its not inside any of the other views 
horizontalConstraints.isActive = true
verticalConstraints.isActive = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

OR

Update constraints.constants for the horizontal and vertical constraints  when user is moving the view (Not a good approach) and make it zero again if it's not inside of any other view

```
//make it true again if its not inside any of the other views 
horizontalConstraints.constant = change in horizontal direction
verticalConstraints..constant =  change in vertical direction
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**Edit** As you said constraints is nil after setting isActive = false because 
what isActive actually do is add and remove those constraints as Apple doc says

> Activating or deactivating the constraint calls addConstraint(*:) and removeConstraint(*:) on the view that is the closest common ancestor of the items managed by this constraint. Use this property instead of calling addConstraint(*:) or removeConstraint(*:) directly.

So making constraints strong reference does solve the issue but I think setting the strong reference to IBOutelet is not a good idea and adding and removing constraints programmatically is better. check out this question deallocating constraints

Comment: strange behaviour if I go with the 2nd approach .. setting isActive to false makes the constraint  variable to go nil .... so I can't set it to true again.

Comment: Solved this issue by making the outlets strong instead of weak, thanks for you help you should also update your answer

Comment: Yes, I checked with sample project it becomes nil, I have done this earlier making .isActive true/false I never get nil may be because i used to create programmatically,